# Load image from property of the result

Tags: jquery

I have a empty div, `#imgContainer`, and a dynamic jQuery function that loads an image using a URL to a Web API server.

```
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
```

```js
$("#btnShow").click(function () {
  $('<img src="' + "http://localhost:49998/api/Picture/user/GetUserImage?userName=John" + '">').on("load", function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#imgContainer');
  });
});
```

Now there is a change at the server side. Instead of returning an image, it returns an object named "ImageData" that contains two properties. "image" that holds the image, and another attribute named "date" that holds the upload date of the image.

How I can retrieve the information, and display the image?

Comment: Check the image file permission in your server, is it too restrictive? Does your server run apache and SE Linux? If you are using linux, what's the permission of the file?

Comment: What exactly is the content in the `image` property? Is it a string URL, or the image as Base64, or something else entirely?

Comment: if you're getting the object, then try to use var_dump to see what data it contains

Answer (score 1):

Uses

`$('<img src="' + "http://localhost:49998/api/Picture/user/GetUserImage?userName=John" + '">').on("load", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    $(this).appendTo('#imgContainer');
  });`

to see what data it contains.

Afterwards you should be able to navigate and just retrieve the image as for an array.